# How should I go about implementing MVVM architecture pattern in my project?

Tags: android, kotlin, viewmodel, android-livedata, android-mvvm

I know this is a very documented topic, but I couldn't find a way to implement it in my project, even after spending hours trying to figure it out.

My root problem is that I have a `RecyclerView` with an Adapter whose content isn't updating as I'd like. I'm a beginner in Android, so I didn't implement any MVVM or such architecture, and my project only contains a repository, fetching data from Firebase Database, and passing it to a list of `ShowModel`, a copy of said list being used in my Adapter to display my shows (In order to filter/sort them without modifying the list with all shows).

However, when adding a show to the database from another Activity, my Adapter isn't displaying the newly added show (as detailed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74021740/refreshing-recyclerview-after-adding-an-element-to-the-database))

I was told to use `LiveData` and `ViewModel`, but even though I started understanding how it works after spending time researching it, I don't fully get how I should use it in order to implement it in my project.

Currently I have the following classes:

The Adapter:

```
class ShowAdapter(private val context: MainActivity, private val layoutId: Int, private val textNoResult: TextView?) : RecyclerView.Adapter<ShowAdapter.ViewHolder>(), Filterable {
    var displayList = ArrayList(showList)

    class ViewHolder(view : View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(view){
        val showName: TextView = view.findViewById(R.id.show_name)
        val showMenuIcon: ImageView = view.findViewById(R.id.menu_icon)
    }

    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ViewHolder {
        val view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(layoutId, parent, false)
        return ViewHolder(view)
    }

    @SuppressLint("NewApi", "WeekBasedYear")
    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {
        val currentShow = displayList[position]
        val index = holder.adapterPosition

        holder.showName.text = currentShow.name

        holder.itemView.setOnClickListener{ // Display show content
            val intent = Intent(context, DetailsActivity::class.java)
            intent.putExtra("position", index)
            startActivity(context, intent, null)
        }

        holder.showMenuIcon.setOnClickListener{
            val popupMenu = PopupMenu(context, it)
            popupMenu.menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.show_management_menu, popupMenu.menu)
            popupMenu.show()
            popupMenu.setOnMenuItemClickListener {
                when(it.itemId){
                    R.id.edit -> { // Edit show
                        val intent = Intent(context, AddShowActivity::class.java)
                        intent.putExtra("position", index)
                        startActivity(context, intent, null)
                        return@setOnMenuItemClickListener true
                    }
                    R.id.delete -> { // Delete show
                            val repo = ShowRepository()
                            repo.deleteShow(currentShow)
                            displayList.remove(currentShow)
                            notifyItemRemoved(index)
                            return@setOnMenuItemClickListener true
                    }
                    else -> false
                }
            }
        }
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int = displayList.size

    // Sorting/Filtering methods
}
```

The fragment displaying the adapter:

```
class HomeFragment : Fragment() {
    private lateinit var context: MainActivity
    private lateinit var verticalRecyclerView: RecyclerView
    private lateinit var buttonAddShow: Button
    private lateinit var showsAdapter: ShowAdapter

    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
        val view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false)

        context = getContext() as MainActivity

        buttonAddShow = view.findViewById(R.id.home_button_add_show)
        buttonAddShow.setOnClickListener{ // Starts activity to add a show
            startActivity(Intent(context, AddShowActivity::class.java))
        }

        verticalRecyclerView = view.findViewById(R.id.home_recycler_view)
        showsAdapter = ShowAdapter(context, R.layout.item_show, null)

        verticalRecyclerView.adapter = showsAdapter

        return view
    }
}
```

The MainActivity:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        loadFragment(HomeFragment())
    }

    private fun loadFragment(fragment: Fragment){
        val repo = ShowRepository()

        if(showsListener != null) databaseRef.removeEventListener(showsListener!!)

        repo.updateData{
            val transaction = supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
            transaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, fragment)
            transaction.addToBackStack(null)
            if(supportFragmentManager.isStateSaved)transaction.commitAllowingStateLoss()
            else transaction.commit()
        }
    }
}
```

The repository:

```
class ShowRepository {

    object Singleton{
        val databaseRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("shows")
        val showList = arrayListOf<ShowModel>()
        var showsListener: ValueEventListener? = null
    }

    fun updateData(callback: () -> Unit){
        showsListener = databaseRef.addValueEventListener(object : ValueEventListener {
            override fun onDataChange(snapshot: DataSnapshot) {
                showList.clear()

                for(ds in snapshot.children){
                    val show = ds.getValue(ShowModel::class.java)
                    if(show != null) showList.add(show)
                }
                callback()
            }

            override fun onCancelled(p0: DatabaseError) { }
        })
    }

    fun insertShow(show: ShowModel){
        databaseRef.child(show.id).setValue(show)
    }

    fun deleteShow(show: ShowModel){
        databaseRef.child(show.id).removeValue()
    }
}
```

From what I understand of `LiveData` and `ViewModel`, what I should do is creating a `ShowViewModel` containing a `MutableLiveData<List<ShowModel>>` containing the shows, and then observe it in my `HomeFragment` and update the adapter depending on the changes happening. However, everytime I start something to implement it, I encounter a situation where I'm lost and don't know what I should do, which leads me back to square one once again. I've been trying this for more than a week without progressing even a little bit, and that's why I'm here, hoping for some insight.

Sorry for the silly question and the absurd amount of informations, and hoping someone will be able to help me understand what I do wrong/should do.

Comment: listen for changes https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/listen instead of querying one-off for changes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(this ended up longer than I meant it to be - hope it's not too much! There's a lot to learn, but you don't have to make it super complicated at first)

Broadly, working backwards, it should go like this:

**Adapter**

- displays whatever the Fragment tells it to (some kind of `setData` function that updates its internal list and refreshes)
- passes events to the `Fragment` (`deleteItem(item)`, `showDetails(item)` etc.) - **don't** have the `Adapter` doing things like starting Activites, that's not its responsibility

**Fragment**

- grabs a reference to any `ViewModel`s (only certain components like Fragments and Activities can actually "own" them)
- `observe`s any `LiveData` (or `collect`s `Flow`s if you're doing it that way) on the VM, and updates stuff in the UI in response
- e.g. `model.shows.observe(viewLifecycleOwner) { shows -> adapter.setData(shows) }`
- handles UI events and calls methods on the VM in response, e.g. click listeners, events from the `Adapter`

**ViewModel**

- acts as a go-between for the UI (the `Fragment`) and the data layer (the *repository*)
- exposes methods for handling events like deleting items, interacts with the data layer as required (e.g. calling the appropriate delete function)
- exposes data state for the UI to observe, so it can react to changes/updates (e.g. a `LiveData` containing the current list of shows that the data layer has provided)

That's the basic setup - the VM exposes data which the UI layer observes and reacts to, by displaying it. The UI layer also produces events (usually down to user interaction) which are passed to the VM. You can read more about this general approach [in this guide about app architecture](https://developer.android.com/topic/architecture) - it's worth reading because not only is it recommended as a way to build apps, a lot of the components you use in modern Android are designed with this kind of approach in mind (like the *reactive* model of wiring stuff up).

---

You could handle the `Adapter` events like this:

```
// in your Adapter
var itemDeletedListener: ((Item) -> Unit)? = null

// when the delete event happens for an item
itemDeletedListener?.invoke(item)


// in your Fragment
adapter.itemDeletedListener = { viewModel.deleteItem(it) }
```

which is easier than implementing an interface, and lets you wire up your Adapter similar to doing `setOnClickListener` on a button. Notice we're passing the actual `Item` object here instead of a list index - generally this is easier to work with, you don't need to maintain multiple copies of a list just so you can look up an index given to you by something else. Passing a unique ID can make sense though, especially if you're working with a database! But usually the object itself is more useful and consistent

---

The data layer is the tricky bit - the ViewModel needs to communicate with that to get the current state. Say you delete an item - you then need to get the current, updated list of shows. You have three approaches:

### *Call the delete function, immediately after fetch the current data, and set it on the appropriate `LiveData`*

This can work, but it's not very *reactive* - you're doing one action, then immediately doing another because you know your data is stale. It would be better if the new data just *arrived automatically* and you could *react* to that by pushing it out. The other issue is that calling the *delete* function might not have an immediate effect - if you fetch the current data, nothing might have changed yet. It's better if the data layer is responsible for announcing updates.

**This is the simplest approach though, and probably a good start!** You could run this task in a coroutine (`viewModelScope.launch { // delete and fetch and update LiveData }`) so any slowness doesn't block the current thread.

### *Have the data layer's functions return the current, updated data that results*

Similar to above, you're just sort of pushing the fetching into the data layer. This requires all those functions to be written to return the current state, which could take a while! And depending on what data you want, this might be impossible - if you have an active query on some data, how does the function know what specific data to return?

### *Make the ViewModel observe the data it wants, so when the data layer updates, you get the results automatically*

This is the recommended *reactive* approach - again it's that two-way idea. The VM calling a function on the data layer is *completely separate* from the VM receiving new data. One thing just happens as a natural consequence of the other, they don't need to be tied together. You just need to wire them up right!

---

How do you actually do that though? If you're working with something like [Room](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room/async-queries), that's already baked in. Queries can return async data providers like `LiveData` or `Flow`s - your VM just needs to observe those and expose the results, or just expose them directly. That way, when a table is updated, any queries (like the current *shows*) push a new value, and the observers receive it and do whatever they need to do, like telling the `Adapter` to display the data. It all Just Works once it's wired up.

Since you have your own repo, you need to expose your own data sources. You could have a `currentShows` `LiveData` or (probably preferably) the *flow* equivalent, `StateFlow`. When the repo initialises, and when any data is changed, it updates that `currentShows` data. Anything observing that (e.g. the VM, the Fragment through a `LiveData`/`Flow` that the VM exposes) will automatically get the new values. So broadly:

```
// Repo

// this setup is exactly the same as your typical LiveData, except you need an initial value
private val _currentShows = MutableStateFlow<List<Show>>(emptyList()) // or whatever default
val currentShows: StateFlow<List<Show>> = _currentShows

fun deleteItem(item: Item) {
    // do the deletion
    // get the updated show list
    _currentShows.value = updatedShowList
}


// ViewModel

// one way of doing things - you have a lot of options! This literally just exposes
// the state from the data layer, and turns it into a LiveData (if you want that)
val currentShows = repo.currentShows.asLiveData()


// Fragment

// wire things up so you handle new data as it arrives
viewModel.currentShows.observe(viewLifecycleOwner) { shows -> adapter.setData(shows) }
```

That's basically it. I've skimmed over a lot because honestly, there's a lot to learn with this - especially about `Flow`s and coroutines if you're not already familiar with those. But hopefully that gives you an overview of the general idea, and don't be afraid to take shortcuts (like just updating your data in the ViewModel by setting its `LiveData` values) while you're learning and getting the hang of it. Definitely give that *app architecture* guide a read, and also the guides for `ViewModel`s and `LiveData`. It'll start to click when you get the general idea!

Comment: I've not tried implementing yet, but just reading it allowed me to understand quite some things, and it sure cleared up my mind. That was a really complete answer (and easily understandable), thank you so much for taking the time, I'd upvote it again if I could.

Comment: @Balizok no worries, glad it helped! It's a big topic and there's a lot to get your head around, and often a lot of changes you have to make if you've already designed things another way (ask me how I know) but it makes a lot of sense when you understand the bigger picture. This might be handy too: https://youtu.be/fSB6_KE95bU it gets into some of the technicalities of coroutines and Flows, so don't worry too much if that's a bit confusing right now, but I think it does a nice job of giving you a sense of what's going on and why it's designed that way. Then you can use the parts you like!

Comment: I know it's been some time since you answered, but I just wanted to update you because I think I finally managed to grasp how it all works (even if I still need to delve into some points), and it was mostly thanks to you, so I wanted to thank you once more for your amazing answer ;)

Comment: @Balizok haha thanks, I appreciate it! And it's cool you managed to wrangle it, there's a lot to learn and put together - so, nice! (And hey I'm still learning some of it too)